# Merge two tables but keep both values

Tags: r, merge

I can't seem to figure out how to merge two tables into one table but keeping both values in one column.
Perhaps someone can push me in the right direction on how to resolve this? Any ideas would be helpfull!

So I have the first table:

```
set0 <- data.frame(A = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B"),
                         B = c("E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"))

set0 <- table(transform(set0, 
                B = ifelse(B %in% c('F', 'G'), 'V', 
                           ifelse(B %in% c('H', 'I'), 'R', B))))
#> set0
#   B
#A   E R V
#  A 1 2 0
#  B 1 1 1
#  C 0 0 2
#  D 0 1 1
```

The table has the following values:

```
> str(set0)
 'table' int [1:4, 1:3] 1 1 0 0 2 1 0 1 0 1 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ A: chr [1:4] "A" "B" "C" "D"
  ..$ B: chr [1:3] "E" "R" "V"
```

And I have the second table (with the same values as above):

```
cset0 <- chisq.test(set0)$expected
#   B
#A     E   R   V
#  A 0.6 1.2 1.2
#  B 0.6 1.2 1.2
#  C 0.4 0.8 0.8
#  D 0.4 0.8 0.8
```

I'd like to merge these tables to something like this:

```
#A       E         R         V
#  A  1 [0.6]   2 [1.2]   0 [1.2]
#  B  1 [0.6]   1 [1.2]   1 [1.2]
#  C  0 [0.4]   0 [0.8]   2 [0.8]
#  D  0 [0.4]   1 [0.8]   1 [0.8]
```

I've tried to make a CrossTable [gmodels] but as with that I cant figure out how to get the same outcome as set0 as shown above. I am quite new at merging tables as I never had to do this before. So any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for display purposes you can use `sprintf` :

```
set0[] <- sprintf('%s [%s]', set0, cset0)
set0

# B
#A        E       R       V      
#  A 1 [0.6] 2 [1.2] 0 [1.2]
#  B 1 [0.6] 1 [1.2] 1 [1.2]
#  C 0 [0.4] 0 [0.8] 2 [0.8]
#  D 0 [0.4] 1 [0.8] 1 [0.8]
```

Comment: Not sure if it is allowed to ask another question here, if not I will create a new question! The first table now has an addmargins() added to it so the sum of each row and col is mentioned. How would I merge those two tables?

Comment: It would be better to ask it as a new question @RobbieVoort with appropriate example.

Answer (score 0):

Using `paste`

```
set0[] <- paste0(set0, '[', cset0, ']')
```